# Does the homeomorphism between the graph of a function and its domain contradict the domain invariance theorem?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

I'll give some context in case it's important to answer this question. I am reading about charts and atlases. In the document I am reading it is stated that two charts of a topological space must have the same dimension. Given two charts $(U,x)$ and $(V,y)$ of $M$ , where $x:U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y:V \to \mathbb{R}^m$. The transition maps are homeomorphisms that go from  $x(U \cap V) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to y(U \cap V) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$.
If $n \neq m$, then the open set $x(U \cap V)$ would be homeomorphic to the non-open set $y(U \cap V)\times\{0\}^{n-m}$, against the domain invariance theorem (that states that every subspace homeomorphic to an open set is necessarily open) Therefore n=m.

**As a separate thing**, I know the graph of a function is homeomorphic to its domain.
$$\mathcal{G}(f)=\{(x,f(x))\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$$ The domain is $\mathbb{R}^n$. I thing I can write it as  $\mathbb{R}^n\times\{0\}$. So this would be a non-open set, just as they did above, right? So it couldn't be homeomorphic to the graph if the domain invariance theorem is true. What is going on?

Comment: Open subsets of one space can certainly be homeomorphic to non-open subsets of other spaces. Openness is not an intrinsic property of a topological space, but depends on the surrounding space. Homeomorphisms only preserve intrinsic properties, though (like compactness)

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos. Are you saying the domain invariance theorem is false? My book says every subspace homeomorphic to an open set is necessarily open (in $\mathbb{R}^n$)

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. The domain invariance theorem very carefully states in which space the sets are open. Your case is not covered by the theorem because the graph of $f$ and the domain of $f$ are not part of the same larger space, which is what the theorem requires.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos  Isn't the domain $\mathbb{R}^n$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} $ just as the graph?  Moreover, I could write it as $\mathbb{R}^n\times\{0\}$. Both $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the graph are in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Comment: Just a remark, two charts will have the same dimension as long as they refer to the same connected component.

Comment: $\mathbb R^n$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. They don't have any common elements whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Bbb R^n$, seen as $\Bbb R^n \times \{0\} \subseteq \Bbb R^{n+1}$ is **not** open in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ and neither is $\mathcal{G}(f) \subseteq \Bbb R^{n+1}$. So there is no contradiction with invariance of domain at all. Two *non-open* sets can be homeomorphic to their heart's content (e.g. one can be closed and the other non-closed etc). It's only when we have a homeomorphism $h: U \to V$ where $U,V \subseteq \Bbb R^{n+1}$ and *one* of the sets is open ( $U$ or $V$) and the other one is not, that we'd have a problem. As in your atlas case..

Comment: Are $\Bbb R^n \times \{0\}$ and the graph close sets?. Is there a version of the invariance  of domain theorem for closed sets?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Yes, both are closed sets. No, there is no invariance of domain for closed sets : all $\Bbb R^m$ sit as closed sets inside $\Bbb R^n$ for $m \le  n$ e.g. Open sets are special in $\Bbb R^n$ because they always have full dimension (same as surrounding Euclidean space).